# My question is a very basic one about relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am learning about relations right now and I have a question about some terms.

I am told a relation on $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$. Then I am told a relation $R$ on $A$ is reflexive if for all (and this is where I have a problem) $a\in R$, we have $a\sim a$. Ok sure makes sense, but wouldn't the elements of $R$ be ordered pairs? Then does $ (a,b) \sim (c,d)$ even make sense? I am asked to prove if we have two relations $R$ and $S$ and they are both reflexive then their intersection is reflexive. So do I take an arbitrary element in their intersection and shows its in a relation with itself, but again these are ordered pairs that are not components of other ordered pairs... and I am confused.

Comment: $a \sim b$ is a shorthand for $(a, b) \in R$.

Comment: ok take set A, and talk about a relation on it. Call it R. Then to show R is reflexive, I take an element in R (call it a) but the elements in R are ordered pairs our relation is between the elements of A, that are not ordered pairs, so how do I even talk about the elements in R being in a relation, they are the relation....

Comment: Oh, your definition is messed up. It should be for $a \in A$, $a \sim a$.

Comment: No, you take any element $a \in A$ and show that $(a,a)\in R$

Comment: that would imply that a relation is all of AxA not a subset of AxA would it not?

Comment: No, a refelexive relation of $A$ is the subset of $A\times A$ that contains elements of A paired with themselves.  If you think of $A\times A$ as a table, and a relation as a collection of cells from that table, then a reflexive relation is the subset containing all the diagonal cells.

Comment: So if I want to prove that if I have two reflexive relations $R$ and $S$ on a set $A$ then $R\cap S$ is reflexive. Would it go like this

Let $a\in R\cap S$. Then $a\sim_R a$ and $a\sim_S a$ so $a\sim_{R\cap S} a$

or like this 

Let $a\in A$, then $(a,a)\in R \ \wedge (a,a) \in S$ thus $(a,a) \in R\cap S$
?

or neither?

Comment: The later. $\forall a\in A\, [(a,a)\in R\land (a,a)\in S] \iff \forall a\in A\, [(a,a)\in R\cap S]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am learning about relations right now and I have a question about some terms.
>
> I am told a relation on $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$. Then I am told a relation $R$ on $A$ is reflexive if for all (and this is where I have a problem) $a∈R$, we have $a∼a$.

No, it's for all $a\in A$ that $a\sim a$.  Which means that $(a,a)\in R$

---

Take, for example, $A=\{1,2,3\}$ then a reflexive relation of $A$ is one that contains all of $(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)$.  It may contain other pairs from $A\times A$, but it cannot contain less.

---

> I am asked to prove if we have two relations R and S and they are both reflexive then their intersection is reflexive. So ...

So you have a minimum list of elements that are in any reflexive relation (of $A$), by definition.  If all of these elements are in the intersection then that too is a reflexive relation (of $A$).

$R$ is reflexive so: $\forall a\, (a\in A\to (a,a)\in R)$

$S$ is reflexive so: $\forall a\, (a\in A\to (a,a)\in S)$

Can you use this to show that the following must be true? $\forall a\, (a\in A\to (a,a)\in (R\cap S))$.

Comment: Ok with the correct understanding of the definition the problem seems trivial for both union and intersection. Thanks.

Comment: @zb In this context you can define the "diagonal" $\triangle\left(A\right):=\left\{ \left(a,a\right):a\in A\right\} $. It is a reflexive relation on $A$ itself and a relation $R$ on $A$ is reflexive if and only if $\triangle\left(A\right)\subseteq R$.